# Cannot add initial data to database with Spring Boot (Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I use Hibernate in my Spring Boot app and populate the tables without any problem. However, I am trying to add 2 record to one of the populated table using `import.sql` on the classpath.

```
INSERT INTO role(id, role_type) VALUES(1, 'ADMIN');
INSERT INTO role(id, role_type) VALUES(2, 'USER');
```

I also set the following properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

When I run the app, tables are created and the data is populated, and tables are created. However, I got *"Error executing DDL : alter table user_role drop foreign key"* error.

When I update `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` as shown below, there is no error and tables are created. BUT, records are not inserted to the role table:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

So, how can I insert data when I run the app without any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import.sql` will only be executed provided that `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is set to `create` or `create-drop`.

Alternatively you can use `data.sql` it will be executed irrespective of `hibernate.ddl` configuration.

Using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update` and `data.sql` should solve both of your error.

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always 
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

[Use defer-datasource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database?fireglass_rsn=true#2-hibernate-and-datasql)

Comment: Actually, I tried to use `data.sql` with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update`, but it does not help to add records. Then I decided to use Flyway.

Comment: @Rosa try adding this property  spring.sql.init.mode=always 

for Spring Boot before 2.5:
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=true

Comment: Thanks, but I also tried that way before asking the question and this time I am getting "Table 'student-db.role' doesn't exist" error. I think when `data.sql` is executed, Hibernate has not created tables. So, is there a solution for that? It is really weird.

Comment: Perfect!... Solved the problem, thanks a lot.